# C++ distinguish Lambdas from Function pointers inside a vector

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lambda

I'm writing a little event manager class where I store some function pointers inside a vector. I use `std::function<void(int)>` as vector type, I tested inserting inside it lambdas and normal functions and it works:

```
void t(int p){
  /*things*/
}
[...]
event.bind([](int p){/*things*/});
event.bind(t);
```

Now, *(at a certain point I need to delete lambdas but not functions,)* my question is:

**Is it possible to distinguish lambdas from functions? If yes, how?**

**EDIT:**
Since I clarified my doubts, this question becomes just what the title says

Comment: What do you mean, delete lambdas?  And why are lambdas treated different than function pointers?  Your design looks ... wrong.

Comment: You could instead take a `std::pair` with a `bool` as the second parameter and that `bool` would signal whether it is a function pointer or a lambda.

Comment: If you want to distinguish between lambda's and function pointers, don't treat them the same way by putting them in a single vector... (PS: +1 to Yakk's comment, how so: delete the lambda's?)

Comment: I assume OP means they want to 'delete' them from the vector...

Comment: use BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION (or _func_ in msvc) to get the name of the function . lambdas are generally named with a scheme by the compiler. Check to see  if you can find a pattern. This will not be very portable, though.

Comment: @Yakk Lambdas are pointers, aren't they? But they point to an anonymous function (object) that can be deleted, or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: @RomanHudylko lambdas are function objects. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda.

Comment: You cannot `delete` a lambda. You may want to `remove` or `erase` one.

Comment: @Yakk So, let's say I delete the pointer to the lambda, does the lambda gets removed or not?

Comment: @RomanHudylko ... where is this pointer?  I don't see a pointer.  If you somehow made a pointer to a lambda (for whatever reason), if you delete a pointer to something in automatic storage (not allocated with `new`), your program is ill-formed.  Lambdas are not pointers, lambdas are anonymous types with an `operator()`.  Closures are instances of that type.  You can store a closure within a `std::function` by-value using the miracle of type erasure.

Comment: @Yakk Thank you!!! I thought that lambdas were pointers since `std::function` can collect function pointers too, now I got myself informed a little bit. Since I come from PHP, C++ is sometimes a pain to me :(

Answer (score 4):

The *real* answer is: you don't want to do this. It defeats the point of type-erasing functors if you actually want to know the original type also in case of whatever. This just smells like bad design.

---

What you are potentially looking for is [`std::function::target_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target_type). This is a way to pull out the underlying `type_info` of the target function that the `function` object is storing. Each `type_info` has a `name()`, which can be demangled. Note that this is a very deep rabbit hole and you're basically going to have to hard-code all sorts of weird edge-cases. As I've been doing thanks to Yakk's very loving help.

Different compilers mangle their lambda names differently, so this approach doesn't even resemble portability. Quick checking shows that `clang` throws in a `$` while `gcc` throws `{lambda...#d}`, So we can attempt to take advantage of that by writing something like:

```
bool is_identifier(std::string const& id) {
    return id == "(anonymous namespace)" ||
        (std::all_of(id.begin(), id.end(),
        [](char c){
            return isdigit(c) || isalpha(c) || c == '_';
        }) && !isdigit(id[0]));
}

bool is_lambda(const std::type_info& info)
{
    std::unique_ptr<char, decltype(&std::free)> own {
        abi::__cxa_demangle(info.name(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr),
        std::free
    };

    std::string name = own ? own.get() : info.name();

    // drop leading namespaces... if they are valid namespace names
    std::size_t idx;
    while ((idx = name.find("::")) != std::string::npos) {
        if (!is_identifier(name.substr(0, idx))) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            name = name.substr(idx+2);
        }
    }

#if defined(__clang__)
    return name[0] == '$';
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    return name.find("{lambda") == 0;
#else
    // I dunno?
    return false;
#endif
}
```

And then throw that in your standard erase-remove idiom:

```
void foo(int ) { }
void bar(int ) { }
long quux(long x) { return x; }

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::function<void(int)>> v;

    v.push_back(foo);
    v.push_back(bar);
    v.push_back(quux);
    v.push_back([](int i) { std::cout << i << '\n';});

    std::cout << v.size() << std::endl; // prints 4

    v.erase(
        std::remove_if(
            v.begin(),
            v.end(),
            [](std::function<void(int)> const& f){
                return is_lambda(f.target_type());
            }),
        v.end()
        );

    std::cout << v.size() << std::endl; // prints 3
}
```

Comment: `template<class F> struct evil { F f; template<class...Ts>auto operator()(Ts&&...ts)const{return f(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);} }; template<class F> evil<std::decay_t<F>> make_evil( F&& f ) { return {std::forward<F>(f)}; } v.push_back( make_evil( [](int x){ std::cout << "evil\n"; } ) );` will be removed by your code, despite not being a lambda.  ;)

Comment: @Yakk Nicely done :) Yeah, I guess the `is_lambda` check would have to be much more refined. Like for clang, it MUST be `some::namespaces::then::$_\d+`.

Comment: You can also do it with a function pointer, but is is a bit of mess: `template<class F> void foo(int); auto blah=[]{}; v.push_back( foo<decltype(blah)> );` does it (first attempt actually didn't work, I think)

Comment: @Yakk There you go, `evil` handled :)

Comment: `namespace { auto blah = [](int){}; }`?  I guess what I'm saying is, once you start parsing the type id, you better actually parse the type id.  Oh, and does it work on intel compiler?  MSVC?  ;)

Comment: @Yakk LoL. Fixed the anonymous namespace, this was already silly to start with but now it's just absurd. And pfft, those aren't real compilers anyway

Comment: `template<class T> struct foo { auto blah(){ return [](int){}; }; };` then `std::cout << is_lambda( typeid( foo<int>{}.blah() ) ) << '\n';`  -- [templatized namespace, booyah](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f98614ba591e9a9).  I don't think you can get out of this without a basically full parser.  `foo< decltype(foo<int>{}.blah()) >{}.blah()` can be next, if you want.  I wonder if I can pull off `self = foo< self >{}.blah()`.

Comment: @Yakk I give up. You win.

Comment: @Walter Did I claim it was?

Comment: you didn't, but you didn't say it wasn't either. -- erm now you do.

Answer (score 3):

No, not in general.

A `std::function<void(int)>` can store a function pointer to any function that can be called by passing a single rvalue `int`.  There are an infinite number of such signatures.

The type of a lambda is an unique anonymous class for each declaration.  Two distinct lambdas do not share any type relationship.

You can determine of a `std::function<void(int)>` stores a variable of a specific type, but in both the function pointer and lambda case there is an unbounded number of different types that can be stored in the `std::function` to consider.  And you can only test for "exactly equal to a type".

You can access the type id information, but there is no portable representation there, and generally using that information for anything other than identity matching (and related) or debugging is a bad idea.

Now, a restricted version of the question (can you tell if a `std::function<void(int)>` contains a function pointer of type `void(*)(int)`) is easy to solve.  But in general, doing so remains a bad idea: first, because it is delicate (code far away from the point you use it, like a subtle change to the function signature, can break things), and second, inspecting and changing your behavior based on the type stored in a `std::function` should only be done in extreme corner cases (usually involving updating your code from using `void*` style callbacks to `std::function` style callbacks).

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** This answer presupposes that there is a finite, distinct number of function signatures that may be assigned as event handlers. It assumes that assigning any-old function with the wrong signature is a mistake.

You can use [std::function::target](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target) to determine which ones are the *function pointers* and by process of elimination figure out which ones must be the *lambdas*:

```
void func1(int) {}
void func2(double) {}

int main()
{

    std::vector<std::function<void(int)>> events;

    events.push_back(func1);
    events.push_back([](int){});
    events.push_back(func2);

    for(auto& e: events)
    {
        if(e.target<void(*)(int)>())
            std::cout << "funcion int" << '\n';
        else if(e.target<void(*)(double)>())
            std::cout << "funcion double" << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << "must be lambda" << '\n';
    }
}
```

This works because [std::function::target](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target) returns a *null pointer* if the parameter type doesn't match.

Single variable example:

```
void func(int) {}

int main()
{

    std::function<void(int)> f = func;

    if(f.target<void(*)(int)>())
        std::cout << "not a lambda" << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Could you make me an example of this applied to a single variable `std::function<void(int)>`? Cause I tried to implement your code but I didn't succeed...

Comment: `void problem(double){};  events.push_back(problem);` will not be detected as a function pointer by your above code, but will otherwise compile.

Comment: @Yakk That's why I said "process of elimination", but it wasn't very clear. I updated the code to make it clearer.

Comment: @Galik there are an infinite number of function signatures compatible with `void(int)`.  In particular, `template<class...>struct example{ example(int){} }; void foo( example<char> ); void foo2( example<int, std::string> );` are both storable within a `std::function<void(int)>`.  There is no way to iterate over all function signatures that can be stored in a `std::function` and test each one, so one cannot eliminate the possibility that your `std::function` has a function pointer (unless it is of signature `void()` *and* your compiler fails to implement all standard defect fixes).

Comment: This won't work because there's really lots of different function pointers target types that could be valid. For one thing, `R(*)(int)` for *any* `R`...

Comment: @Galik I did cout to test but it does not work `std::cout<<(callback.target<void(*)(P)>()) ? "f" : "l")<<std::endl;` I get **expected primary-expression before 'void'**. Oh, and P is from a template (don't know if that's the problem).

Comment: @Yakk But the question is only talking about a container that contains functions with a specific signature. You are inventing problems that don't exist. What you are doing is like arguing against an integer array because someone might put a double in it by mistake.

Comment: @RomanHudylko Why is there a `P` in your callback? It should be `int` like: `std::cout<<(callback.target<void(*)(int)>()) ? "f" : "l")<<std::endl;`

Comment: @Galik It's from a template, I think it's the same... or does it matter somehow?

Comment: @Barry Same argument for you. That's like saying an `int array[10];` won't work because people can also assign `double` and `float` to the elements.

Comment: @Galik What? If you assign a `double` to an `int array[10]`, it becomes an `int`. If you assign a `double(*)(int)` to a `std::function<void(int)>`, it's *still* a `double(*)(int)` if you look at `target()`...

Comment: @RomanHudylko Without seeing your actual code its hard to tell. The examples in my answer work on my system. If the template parameter is actually an `int` then it should work. If it is not an int then you need to allow for all the possible types it could be.

Comment: @Barry I mean assigning a `double` to an integer is a mistake just like assigning a function with the wrong signature to a particular event that needs an `int` is a mistake.

Comment: @Galik `std::function<void(int)>` can store a function pointer to any function which is call-compatible with passing a single `int`.  The question was "can you distinguish between one storing a function pointer, and one storing a lambda".  It wasn't "can you distinguish between one storing a function pointer to a function exactly of type `void(int)` and anything else", which is what you answered.

Answer (score 2):

Be it a function pointer or lambda, it ends up as a `std::function<void(int)>` in the `vector`. It is then `std::function<void(int)>`'s responsibility to manage the function pointer or lambda, not yours. That means, you just remove the `std::function<void(int)>`s you want from the `vector`. The destructor of `std::function<void(int)>` knows how to do things right. In your case, that would be doing nothing with function pointers and invoking the destructor of lambdas. `std::function<void(int)>` enables you to treat different things in a nice and uniform way. Don't misuse it.